# tkinter showing multiple buttons with dictionary in multiple frame (object oriented programming)

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

i was making a code with python 3 using tkinter. in a nutshell the code looks like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
class home(tk.Tk):
#consists of frames
class frame1(tk.Frame):
#consists of buttons
class frame2(tk.Frame):
#consists of buttons
```

the problem is i generate multiple buttons with dictionary, but when i grid the button in frame 2 what actually happen is the buttons are located  not in frame 2 but in home. so everytime i switch to frame 1 the button in frame 2 still show up. anyone can give me a solution?

Comment: There's not enough code. Please create a [minimal, _complete_, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

> but when i grid the button in frame 2 what actually happen is the buttons are located not in frame 2 but in home.

You normally place them in a particular frame when the buttons are created, not with grid()

> so everytime i switch to frame 1 the button in frame 2 still show up.

The buttons will show up until you destroy them or grid_forget(), i.e. remove them.  You can also call the "create a new frame with buttons" class as many times as you want.  A separate class for each frame is not necessary, see below for a simple example.

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk     ## Python 2.x
else:
    import tkinter as tk     ## Python 3.x

class Home():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root=root
        self.column=0
        main_frame=tk.Frame(self.root)
        main_frame.grid(row=0)
        but=tk.Button(main_frame, text="Open a Frame of Buttons",
                      command=self.open_another)
        but.grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Button(main_frame, text="Exit Tkinter", bg="red",
              command=self.root.quit).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="we")

    def open_another(self):
        """ A new frame is created every time the botton is pressed
        """
        self.column += 1
        another=ButtonFrame(self.root, self.column)

class ButtonFrame():
    def __init__(self, root, col):
        self.fr=tk.Frame(root)
        self.fr.grid(row=0, column=col)
        but=tk.Button(self.fr,
            text="A new frame with a button "+     str(col)).grid(row=0)
        tk.Button(self.fr, text="Destroy This Frame", bg="orange",
                  command=self.fr.destroy).grid(row=1, column=0)

root=tk.Tk()
H=Home(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: actually i was making multiple frames, where the class home inherit from tk.Tk
i was trying to make the multiple button that i have generated only exist in certain frame only but what actually happened is those buttons appeared in each frame. i use tkraise() to show each frame.

Comment: Can't debug code without any code.  The solution above is the best that can be done.  Maybe start a new thread with some code and a statement as to what doesn't work the way you want it to.

Comment: I'll send the code by email? how about that? i'll send you the source code, can I ask for your email?